# Error installing IDLE extension IdleX-1.11.1

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm trying to install the [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) extension for IDLE. Whether I run the installer from the commandline `python idlex.py` or from Python Launcher, I get the same  errors:

```
$ cd '/Volumes/Pig/Users/arrow/Downloads/idlex-1.11.1/' && 
'/usr/local/bin/pythonw' 
'/Volumes/Pig/Users/arrow/Downloads/idlex-1.11.1/idlex.py'  && 
echo Exit status: $? && exit 1

Oct 15 20:00:29 Niflheimr.local Python[45309] <Error>: 
kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowTags: Invalid connection

Oct 15 20:00:29 Niflheimr.local Python[45309] <Error>: 
kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() 
to catch errors as they are logged.
```

I'm running the Python 2.6 package for Mac on Mac OS 10.7.5

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with Tkinter. See this site: http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Does launching IDLE itself work properly? You can launch it with:

```
python -m idlelib.idle
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have downloaded the zip from idlex site. To install the extension, you need to unzip it and run

```
python setup.py install
```

you will have a similar visual

```
python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/idlexlib
copying idlexlib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/idlexlib
copying idlexlib/launch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/idlexlib
copying idlexlib/extensionManager.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/idlexlib
```

Possible error to be encountered:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/idlexlib': Permission denied
```

If there is permission denied error: use root permission in the command

Cheers